# How to use syslog for else output ( show up with whois - query )?

Tags: command-line, networking, bash

There is log-file `/var/log/syslog`
with the output of ip-addresses
like e.g. `SRC=10.158.0.1`.

I want to scan from this file every printed address in `SRC= ...` and then to make query with `whois (SRC= ...)`.

This query should be monitored.

Mine attempt is wrong and looks like this in a bash-script:

```bsh
#/bin/bash

while [ 1 ]
do
    grep ‘SRC=ip-address’ /var/log/syslog >> /home/$user/topsecret001/pitbull001.txt;
    whois ‘SRC=ip-address’ >> /home/$user/topsecret001/pitbull002.txt;
done
```

Can somebody help with a trick ? How should I define ip-address and how can 
I use command `whois` with this ip-address ?

The output of /var/log/syslog looks like this snippet here :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5859332/

The output of /var/log/syslog looks like this - when there is a little alert (like today) :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5862958/

Idea would be too - to perform a whois-query only if there is "invalid state" popping up in the line of the scrolling syslog.

---

Thank you for your contributions. I have learnt something by your codes. Often the solutions are looking easier than thought like here - cause I thought it would be more difficulty. I think with recent contribution of enzotib then this question is solved already now.

---

see new comment of today (22nd June 2016) referring to 16.04 :

because this bash-script was for times of ipv4 - does then /etc/sysctl.conf needs to be un-commented to enable ipv4 ? - then this script would run ? otherwise there is no whois-output any more like before. Have checked this with uncommenting line 28 and line 33 of /etc/sysctl.conf - then this bash-script in this thread would work, but deliver very few output because provider has enabled firewall (because of no-spy-act ?). This way by this addition of 22nd June 2016 this thread is actualized for 16.04

Comment: When there are several correct answers at same time, then the least reputation will get the bounty, because I want to be fair.

Comment: Can you post your `/var/log/syslog` file on http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and us give the link please. This because I don't have nothing like `SRC= ...` in my `/var/log/syslog` file.

Comment: Don't know if I still have the old suiting log-file to this ip-address I mentioned above - but can post the actual of today as snippet with same ip, of course.

Comment: wua ! already now - I don't know whom to give the bounty - will wait and think over 5 to 6 days.

Comment: True ! - I slept a bit ... ;o) am somnambule !

Comment: Yes thank you for re-posting this thread, this is what I was searching for !

Comment: it seems that this script is not running to its full extent any more, because of the change from ipv4 to ipv6 and there are no cable-modems available today (are they prohibited now by "no-spy-act" of USA ?) - this script was working with cable-modems with fully detailed listing. But today the output is like the user does not need to know anything ...

Comment: In times of ipv6 this is not working any more - apparently /etc/sysctl.conf needs to be un-commented in some lines, but am not finish with testing here - this bash-script only works with ipv4 - if possible someone can answer here (here 16.04 and this post was referring up to time of 12.04 until 14.04) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yet another solution:

```
awk '{ 
      for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) 
        if ($i ~ /^SRC=/) 
          print substr($i, 5) 
    }' /var/log/syslog |
  sort -u |
  while read ip; do
    printf ' === %s ===\n' "$ip"
    whois "$ip"
  done
```

If you only want to select lines of `syslog` containing the string `INVALID STATE`, then the above code can be modified as follows

```
awk '/INVALID STATE/ { 
      for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) 
        if ($i ~ /^SRC=/) 
          print substr($i, 5) 
    }' /var/log/syslog |
  sort -u |
  while read ip; do
    printf ' === %s ===\n' "$ip"
    whois "$ip"
  done
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, but I don't see the reason to apply 10 times `whois $IP`, if the same IP appear 10 times in /var/log/syslog (like is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5859332/). Most probably the result of `whois one_specific_ip` will not change in the near future.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: oh, you're right, changed.

Comment: @enzotib yes true - forgot to say this in question about a little built-in alert-modus. When there is an 'alien' ping or an 'alien' request then syslog list it with announcing "foreign address" in line.

Comment: @enzotib sorry - not "foreign address" is popping up then - instead it is "invalid state" popping up !

Comment: @dschinn1001: see if the modified answer satisfies your new requirement.

Comment: @enzotib - good. Then question is done by your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `sed` command to extract all of the ip the IP addresses from the file, then use `xargs` to run `whois` for each match:

```
sed 's/^.*SRC=\([0-9.]*\).*$/\1/;t;d' < /var/log/syslog | xargs -n1 whois >> output.txt
```

The `s/^.*SRC=\([0-9.]*\).*$/\1/` command replaces lines that contain SRC=x.x.x.x with just the IP address.

The 't;d' commands skips non-matching lines (thereby avoiding a separate `grep` command).

The `xargs` command invokes `whois` once for each address that `sed` outputs.

---

Alternatively, you can find and log the matching lines first, then extract the ip addresses separately:

```
grep -eSRC=[0-9.]* /var/log/syslog | tee grep-output.txt | sed 's/^.*SRC=\([0-9.]*\).*$/\1/' | xargs -n1 whois >> whois-output.txt`
```

Comment: This looks good, above in first solution /var/log/syslog is "docked" simply with '<' ?

Comment: This looks good, above in first solution /var/log/syslog is "docked" simply with '<' ?

Comment: The `<`  sends the contents of /var/log/syslog to `sed` on stdin.

Comment: I get this error: `Usage: whois [OPTION]... OBJECT...`

Comment: Does your syslog file contain any IP addresses?  Add the -r flag to xargs if you need to handle the case where the list of addresses is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the following code is a suitable starting point for you. It probably isn't the optimal solution, but it does its job.

It consists of a for loop over all lines of output of the command within $(). In each iteration of the loop, one line of output is stored in the variable IP. Then, in the loop, the whois command is called with $IP - the content of the variable IP - as argument.

The brackets $() enclose two grep commands - the first one is searching for IP addresses with SRC= written in front of them and the second one takes the output of the first one (via a pipe |) and just takes the IP address. The -o flag of grep causes it to only output the matched part of the lines instead of the full lines.

The regular expression is also not very elegant yet. It is searching for three groups, each consisting of one to three digits and a dot, followed again by one to three digits. To keep the script readable, I chose to use -E extended regular expressions. The "normal" grep command would require a backslash in front of every round and curly bracket...

```
for IP in \
 $(grep  -E "SRC=([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[[0-9]{1,3}" -o  /var/log/syslog  | \
 grep -E "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[[0-9]{1,3}" -o);
    do whois $IP;
done
```

Comment: This solution is a more didactic one.

Answer (score 2):

Your script should look like this:

```bsh
#/bin/bash

grep 'SRC=' /var/log/syslog | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[ \t]+|\\|"} {print $13}' | uniq >> ~/topsecret001/pitbull001.txt

for ip in $(sed -e 's/SRC=//g' ~/topsecret001/pitbull001.txt)
do 
    whois $ip >> ~/topsecret001/pitbull002.txt
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For to add option - in case of popping up "INVALID STATE" - would then work this ? :

```
awk '{

    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)

      if ($i ~ /^SRC=/)

         print substr($i, 5)

   }' /var/log/syslog | sort -u | while read ip; 

do

   printf ' INVALID STATE ' && printf ' === %s ===\n' "$ip"

   whois "$ip"

 done
```

Comment: This code of enzotib works - after tested it. So this would then already work as new daemon.