# Is this because of a new version of whois or should I try out matriz for ipv6 (is ipv4 too old?)

Tags: command-line, networking, server, bash, scripts

This is concerning an old script from 2013 which some Ubuntu-Forum Users and Users at askubuntu came up with, together with me. The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /^SRC=/)
            print substr($i, 5)
}' /var/log/syslog | sort -u | while read ip; 
do
    printf ' INVALID STATE ' && printf ' =.|=.|=.|= %n =.|=.|=.|=\n ' | "$ip";
    whois "$ip" >> log-002.txt;
done
```

Should I place a matriz here in the variable ip to make a scanable
ipv6 Address? Or is this due to a new version of whois?  A correction to this script will be rewarded.

Obviously the provider (unitymedia) has a new firewall which makes a whois-query impossible.  Should I wait for a new update of whois? Or can this problem be solved?

The result of this script ends as follows:

> `INVALID STATE ./pitbull-001.sh: Zeile 8: 2a02:0908:fd60:9200:b196:36be:5aa1:b60b: command not found
>    INVALID STATE ./pitbull-001.sh: Zeile 8: 2a02:0908:fd60:9200:ba70:f4ff:fef3:2df3: command not found
>    INVALID STATE ./pitbull-001.sh: Zeile 8: fe80:0000:0000:0000:0a95:2aff:fe7a:bca7: command not found
>    INVALID STATE ./pitbull-001.sh: Zeile 8: fe80:0000:0000:0000:ba70:f4ff:fef3:2df3: command not found`

But whois does work when the ipv6 address is given explicitly at the command line:

> whois 2a02:0908:fd60:9200:b196:36be:5aa1:b60b:

It seems as if the whois database is partially damaged, or as if somebody is prohibiting queries?

The difference is, that when making a query at homepage http://whois.net after entering the ip-numbers there into query-field, then results are not the same like when making whois-query locally at your machine.

In case the text of this thread is inappropriate, then please do adjust it to proper English. My syntax is different than your syntax. :-)

Comment: Could you add links to the original Ubuntu-Forum and askubuntu articles?  Also, what is the correct output are you expecting?  Finally, what is matriz (could you give an example or link)?

Comment: I found it: the original link is http://askubuntu.com/questions/307041/how-to-use-syslog-for-else-output-show-up-with-whois-query.  That script looks like it should work with ipv6 as well as ipv4.

Comment: @Gsxr1k - Yes true, this was the page. Thank you for the link. Think you have done it. But will wait for else suggestions. :o)

Comment: @Gsxr1k - only modifying with an 'echo'-command is a bit too economical ... I have re-edited my question.

Comment: @braiam - my question was explicit enough to solve it not too economically like only by an echo-command ... at http://whois.net the queries are different than here ...

Comment: what do you mean by too economical?  Please could you give us an example of the output you would like.  I get the same information from whois.net as I do from the whois command line.

Comment: @Gsxr1k - can you build into the script a re-direction with the link to http://whois.net but the query should go into this ip-query-window there. Then you have won. thank you - :o) if this not works, then dont worry, you get the reward with 100 points. Yes ?

Comment: whois.net doesn't seem to look up ip addresses (of any sort, ipv6 or ipv4), but only domain names.  You could get links to look up on a different whois website just by changing the echo line: for example, changing it to `echo "https://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/$ip"` would give you a who.is link.  But anyway, the output of the whois command, which should contain everything of relevance, will go into the log-002.txt file (as it did with your original script), so it might be better just to look there.

Comment: @Gsxr1k - whois.net can handle hexadecimal code in little query-window like this code fe80:0000:0000:0000:0a95:2aff:fe7a:bca7: - but it then has 40 characters (ciphers) and a string allows only up to 32 ciphers or ... ?!

Comment: When I try the ipv6 code you suggest in whois.net, I get results for the domain name `0000.com`, which is not correct.  I don't think whois.net allows looking up ip addresses.

Comment: @Gsxr1k - It is correct and you can use hexadecimal code as ip address. It is not a matter of permittance. It is allowed. and http://0000.net or http://0000.com is a server in China ... it could be that China does not like that to look up them ... the thing is that there has been a version jump from ipv4 to ipv6 and too from perl 5 to perl 6 ... so the syntax of correct bash-scripting is changing then too - I make a check with ...

Comment: @Gsxr1k -  little trick like here and measure the maximum length of a string (when a string is cut off by over-length) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17368067/length-of-string-in-bash ... and hm string-length is taken over without problem even with 120 characters ... so the ip-address should be accepted too. It can be that some servers dislike queries of ip-addresses as numbers but not all servers do dislike this ...   :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what output you are expecting (I will update this answer if it becomes clear), but the error message is caused by piping the output of `printf` to `"$ip"` on line 8, which is interpreted as a command.

The following script will not give errors, but I'm not sure if it's the output you're after:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
        if ($i ~ /^SRC=/)
            print substr($i, 5)
}' /var/log/syslog | sort -u | while read ip; 
do
    printf ' INVALID STATE ' && echo "$ip";
    whois "$ip" >> log-002.txt;
done
```

The output will be appended to the file `log-002.txt` in the current directory (as it already was with your original script).

Comment: this works slightly better but script is stopping and hunging up the phone (breaks off) - it should list the traffic as in syslog ... ?! or it can be that all firms have given up knocking on the phone line ... :-) means then firewall of phone company is finally working this year.

Comment: there is no complete archive available at http://askubuntu.com - otherwise I could be more elaborately.

Comment: This is the post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/307041/how-to-use-syslog-for-else-output-show-up-with-whois-query.  I suggest you use their script, which will work with ipv6 as well as ipv4.

Comment: as you can see this question is actualized for 16.04 here, after I edited the question a bit (about /etc/sysctl.conf - file) : http://askubuntu.com/questions/307041/how-to-use-syslog-for-else-output-show-up-with-whois-query